# Closing messagebox if no is clicked

Tags: vb.net, textbox

I have about 5 hidden textbox, and 1 button that when I click It it shows the hiddentext 1 by 1, but what I want to do is when I click the button once only 1 textbox appears and then a message box will appear saying "Do you want to Continue" YES or NO? if I press Yes, then the 2nd textbox will appear, but when I press No the messagebox should be closed.

I have this Code on the Button:

```
Private Sub revealtxtbox_Click(ByVal senders As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles revealtxtbox.Click

txtbox1.visible = True
If MsgBox("Do you Want to Continue", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Sample System") = MsgBoxResult.Yes then
txtbox2.visible = true

Elseif MsgBoxResult.Yes then
txtbox3.visible = true

Elseif MsgBoxResult.Yes then
txtbox4.visible = true

Elseif MsgBoxResult.Yes then
txtbox5.visible = true

End if
```

the code above somewhat works but when I press NO, the txtbox3 shows and the msgbox closed, it should not show txtbox3, it should only close the msgbox.

Comment: This is a simple issue and a little debugging will help... Have you tried debugging?

Answer (score -1):

Try something more like this instead:

```
Private Sub revealtxtbox_Click(ByVal senders As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles revealtxtbox.Click

  txtbox1.visible = True

  If MsgBox("Do you Want to Continue", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Sample System") <> MsgBoxResult.Yes then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  txtbox2.visible = true

  If MsgBox("Do you Want to Continue", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Sample System") <> MsgBoxResult.Yes then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  txtbox3.visible = true

  If MsgBox("Do you Want to Continue", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Sample System") <> MsgBoxResult.Yes then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  txtbox4.visible = true

  If MsgBox("Do you Want to Continue", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Sample System") <> MsgBoxResult.Yes then
    Exit Sub
  End If

  txtbox5.visible = true

End if
```